# Dynamically generating iframes causing previously generated iframes to refresh unwontedly - when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, post, iframe, dynamic, innerhtml

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am posting form values to multiple dynamically generated iframes, and want the content of each iframe to remain, as I post to another dynamically generated iframe.

As you can see by my example - even just dynamically creating and adding a new iframe via innerHTML +=, causes the previously generated iframes to refresh.

This is not the case if I do not use javascript to create the iframes - if I just write the html ahead of time and post to the already existing iframes, there is not any refresh problem. The previously posted iframes will remain with the posted content.

I do not know how many iframes I will need - so that is why I am using javascript to dynamically generate the iframes.

I am aware that I could use AJAX for this same purpose, but I am not using AJAX for this.

I just need to know why the iframes are refreshing, regardless of there content, when I am dynamically adding another iframe via Javascript and **innerHTML**?

Is there a way to achieve this without the iframes refreshing?

With my example - I am only showing that the iframes are refreshing. I am not posting to them. But the problem shows up the same.

Click the "Add Iframe" button, up to 3 times. note the previous iframe(s) refreshing as the new one is added.

Here is my example code of this problem.

Thanks again.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Content_For_Iframe_Array = new Array("http://www.bing.com", "http://www.wordpress.com/", "http://www.webcrawler.com");

var Inc_iFrame_Num = 0;
function add_iframe_with_content(){
if(Inc_iFrame_Num < 3){
        var iFrame_String ="<iframe frameborder='5' src='"+Content_For_Iframe_Array[Inc_iFrame_Num]+"' scrolling ='yes' id='iFrame_"+Inc_iFrame_Num+"' style='height:300px; width:800px; margin:5px; padding:0px;'></iframe>";
        document.getElementById('iFrame_Container').innerHTML += iFrame_String;
        Inc_iFrame_Num++;
    }
}
</script>



<div style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#CCC; border:thin #7777 solid; width:85px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:14px;" onclick="add_iframe_with_content();">Add Iframe</div>
<div id="iFrame_Container" style="height:300px; width:800px; border:#CCC thin solid;">Div to hold Iframes</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
The proper method is to use `createElement()` and `appendChild()`. (See code below)

But I would still love to know why the innerHTML method refreshes the other iframes?

Here is the correct usage for my example:

```
// PROPER METHOD to place the new iframe
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.frameBorder = 5;
iframe.scrolling ='yes';
iframe.height = "300px";
iframe.width = "800px";
iframe.name = "iFrame_"+Inc_iFrame_Num;
document.getElementById("iFrame_Container").appendChild(iframe);
//
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you solved it, here is why it happened.  The iframes technically didn't refresh, they were destroyed and then recreated.

When you set `innerHTML`, you remove all the existing nodes inside an element, and then generate new nodes based on the HTML snippet you inserted.  Try the following experiment.

```
<div id="el"><button>My Button</button></div>
<script>
    var myElement = document.getElementById('el');
    var button = myElement.firstChild;

    myElement.innerHTML = myElement.innerHTML;

    console.log(button);
    console.log(myElement.firstChild);
    console.log(button == myElement.firstChild);
    console.log(button.parentNode);
</script>
```

Here, you see we have a `<div>` holding a `<button>`.  We store the button as a variable and then "reload" the inner HTML.  In the first two lines of the log the elements look the same, but they are actually two different nodes.  This is evidenced by the fact that line 3 returns false, showing they are different and line 4 shows that `button` doesn't have a parent node.  It is just sitting in memory because we have a reference to it.

As you discovered, the non-destructive way to change an element's children is with DOM methods.  You can use `appendChild` to add an element at the end or `insertBefore` to insert a child at a different position.  Newer browsers support a method called `insertAdjacentHTML` which does what you were originally planning, create HTML from a string and non-destructively insert it at the end of a node.  I don't think support is quite there yet, though, and the other DOM methods are much more well understood.

Comment: Thanks for that thorough explication Brian - I found it very helpful.

Regards,
Ken